# In case of a server error, should I change the URL in the address bar?

Tags: redirects, url, http-code-500

Let's say the user surfs to `http://mysite.com/some-path` and encounters error 500 which leads to a custom error page.

What is the best practice regarding the URL shown in the address bar while in the error page - should I leave `http://mysite.com/some-path` or should I change it to `http://mysite.com/custom-error.aspx`? Is there a good reason **not** to leave the URL as is?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely leave the URL as it as it is typed into the browser. That way search engines, bots, users, etc. will know that that particular URL is not a valid URL. If you were to redirect to another URL, it's possible that bots, etc. could still index the bad URL, which is not what you want.